# valueHasMutated() - comptible with IE 8

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have an `observable array` where I fill with objects like

```
{
    thisId: value.id,
    nom: value.nom,
    isChecked:check
};
```

the code to fill the `observableArray`

```
self.fullFilter = function() {
    var check;
    self.thisObservableArray.removeAll();
    self.anOther1.removeAll();
    self.anOther2.removeAll();
    $.get("data/"+self.currentOngletId()+"?ajax=1", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $.each(item, function(j, value) {
                check = null;
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        try{
                            if(value.observable_value.length > 0){
                                check = "checked";
                            }
                            var elem = {
                                thisId: value.id,
                                nom: value.nom,
                                isChecked:check
                            };
                            self.thisObservableArray().push(elem);
                        } catch(e){
                            console.warn('fullfilter -> observable_value '+e)
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //an other same code different variables
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //an other same code different variables
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
        try {
            self.thisObservableArray.valueHasMutated();
            self.anOther1.valueHasMutated();
            self.anOther2.valueHasMutated();
        } catch(e){
            self.error("fullfilter",e);
        }
    });
};
```

When I try with IE 8, I have this error

> Unable to parse bindings
>
> Bindings value: attr:{for:'thisObservableArray-'+$data.thisId}
>
> Message : Identifier, string or number expected

the part of the view where the error is found

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Statut</legend>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: thisObservableArray()">
            <li>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label data-bind="attr:{for:'thisObservableArray-'+$data.thisId}">
                    <input class="observable-input" data-bind="attr:{id:'thisObservableArray-'+$data.thisId, name:'thisObservableArray['+$data.id+']', checked: $data.isChecked}"  type="checkbox"/>
                    <span data-bind="text: $data.nom"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    /ul>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 does not support attribute selectors in Compatibility Mode.

You will need to have a Doctype `(<!doctype html>)` that triggers Standards Mode.

[Article](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)

[DocTypes](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

[image]

Comment: sorry but I have to do it because in my company I saw on the stats, **lots of people are using IE8 yet**, and I am agree with you

Comment: yeah totally get it, alot of companies i develop for request to be compatible with ie. and it does create a lot of issues for no reason. see edit above